# How to connect a microphone to apply audio signal to electronic circuit?

Tags: integrated-circuit, microphone, power-electronics, signal-processing

I am working on a project where we have to design a band pass filter signals in audio frequency range. We have tested the filter design using Signal generator already, and now we want to see if it works with actual audio signal which has those frequencies in/out of it Passband. Is there any specific IC or something which can help me for this? We are using simple Active filter for filtering. Also, will it actually work as it was working with Signal Generator?

Comment: What do you mean by "**actual** audio signal"?  If you've tested the filter with a signal generator, I assume you've tested it at audio *frequencies*, i.e., 20Hz - 20kHz.  What type of other test do you have in mind?  White noise?  Pink noise?  Heavy Metal?

Comment: No, Since Signal generator generates ideal signals, I wanted to test the filter design on real sudio signals, including noise and other features into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Electret microphone capsules are very easy to use. Just give them a bias voltage and amplify the output signal. They have a built-in JFET that does the hard work. Here is an example [schematic](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/Amplified-Mic-Electret-v14.pdf) (from [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9964)).

[image]

Many electret mic capsules are available, with slightly different size, pedigree and frequency response. The 2.2K RL is more-or-less standard.